# Django - Update the second list_filter field in real time according to first field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-tools

So I'm trying to improve my django knowledge and I'm working on this personal project in which I have two categories, the main one which is more general and a subcategories filter.

An example would be main_category=smartphone, sub_category=samsung_phones.

My class in models.py would be:

```
class Products(models.Model):

    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    main_category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And my class in admin.py would be:

```
class ProductsAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_filter = ['main_category', 'sub_category']
    ...
```

Now what I wanna do is that, in my /admin/ page, I want to change the contents of 'sub_category' filter -in real-time- and according to what I selected in 'main_category'. Is this possible? Because right now it really doesn't do anything other than taking space so having a main_category filter in itself is useless. I think this should be an easy thing to do but I can't find any documentation about it.

Django version is 1.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with a jQuery injection:

```
class ProductsAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_filter = ['main_category', 'sub_category']
    ...

    class Media(object):
        js = (
            'app/js/myscript.js',  # app static folder
        )
```

If you do not know the data upfront or it changes a lot, and thus are unable to construct a jQuery/javascript function to control the 2 filter elements, you need to override the change_list function and template to inject dynamic js/jQuery.

Or, because I am too lazy and nothing else matters, I would just make a js file, which I would override with the dynamic js everytime you visit the admin page.

EDIT 1:
the js file could be something like this (off course this can be much improved, but it is up to you):

```
// save here your array with data
my_main_category = {
  "": ['Samsung', 'Nokia', 'Dacia', 'Alfa Romeo', 'Volga'], // add them all
  "Smartphones": ['Samsung', 'Nokia'],
  "Cars": ['Dacia', 'Alfa Romeo', 'Volga']
};

// copy options to repopulate sub category select
var $sub_category_options = $('select[data-name="sub_category"] > option').clone();

$('select[data-name="main_category"]').on('change', function () {
    $('select[data-name="sub_category"]').empty().append($sub_category_options);
    $('select[data-name="sub_category"] option').each(function () {
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), my_main_category[$('select[data-name="main_category"]').val()])) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I do know the data upfront, and they don't change at all. So I think injecting jQuery might work. But I'm not that familiar with JS to be honest, would you mind referring to me a relevant link/doc where I can see how I might do this?

Comment: Helicopter see my edit. I did not test it, but is should point you in the right direction. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dan! I'll look into this.